# How to change button colour in python

Tags: python, button

I would want to create a button with tkinter that when you click it then it changes colour. I konw that I can do it by deleting the button but is there any other possibilitis.

Comment: What GUI framework are you using? There are many and the answer will be different for each one. It may be best to also show how you're creating the button.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a lot of options. You can use many GUI libraries like Kivy, Tkinter. But as i dont know what you are using, i am just gonna make a program in Tkinter.

here is the code -

```
# importing modules
from tkinter import *
import random

# making a window
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

# just for decoration or the Background Color
mainframe = Frame(root, bg="#121212", width=400, height=400)
mainframe.pack()

# the function changing color


def color_changing(buttonObject):
    
    # randomizes the color in hexcode
    r = lambda: random.randint(0, 255)
    color = '#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(), r(), r())
    
    # .config configures an Object in Tkinter
    buttonObject.config(bg=color)
    

# making a button
button = Button(root, width=10, font=('Segoe UI', 32, "bold"), text="Click Me", command=lambda: color_changing(button))

# root in Button() is the place where the button has to be placed
# text, width, font, etc are all attributes
# command is a simple way to call a function

# placing it in a specific location
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

# making the window so it does not stop running till it is said to be

root.mainloop()
```